# Enrich the http request header in envoyproxy from the database

Tags: rest, architecture, istio, envoyproxy

Is it possible to enrich the http request header in envoyproxy from the database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the headers, there are examples on the Istio website for this: https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/control-headers/

Manipulate it somehow from the database is more difficult. You probably need a you own service in the k8s cluster, which will make queries in the database and, based on the logic you need, patch the configuration of Istio entities.
You can try to implement this by writing Mutating Configuration Webhook perhaps...